# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I don't know why I am getting this exception, I think it's more about flutter itself instead of code.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```